# Calculate the average sales per day in 2010.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, average

In 2005, Company K was 730 000 units of the car market. Total sales is 50% of the total cars sold in 2010. Calculate the average sales per day in 2010.

Calculation:

> Total sales in 2010 = $50\% \times 730 000 = 365000$
>
> Average sales per day in 2010 = $\frac{365000}{365} = 1000$

Refer to my exercise book, the answer is 4000. Are my calculations wrong?

Comment: Just = (2*730000)/365 = 4000

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Company K sells $730000$ cars per year in 2005, and that is 50% of the total sales in 2010, then, letting the total sales per day in 2010 be $x$, there are $365 * x$ total sales in 2010, and 50% of $365 * x$ will be equal to $730000$. Putting this all into one equation gives

$730000 = \frac{50}{100} * 365 * x$, or

$73000000 = 50 * 365 * x$, or

$1460000 = 365 * x$, or

$4000 = x$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Now i get it.

Answer (score 1):

Company K doubled its sales between 2005 and 2010 -- its sales in 2005 were half of those in 2010.  However you calculated that their sales went down by half.  That is your error.